# Nintendo Network Issues (3DS)

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

So I recently found my 3DS, but I had changed the password on my NNID (Nintendo network) before I found it. So I re-signed in with my new password, but when trying to launch an app, it shows a message saying to "Redownload from the e-shop". So I go to the e-shop and find a game in the search that I own, I tried to redownload it but it says its downloaded already.

When I went to the home screen, everything I downloaded from the eshop was gone. Even my themes. Trying to get to my purchased themes on the theme shop shows theres an update available and I click install, but shows the error code: 009-4079: Could not access SD card. But the SD can read the theme that was set (Simple Blue) And 3 dsiware games. Everything else just cannot be downloaded.

Everything that was downloaded cannot be found in the data management options in the settings.

What should I do?

Comment: DSiware games aren't stored on the SD card, unless you move them there. Even if they're stored on it they can't be played from it. So DSiware games appearing in the menu doesn't mean the SD card works. I don't know about the theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call Nintendo support and get them to help you directly. They will be able to examine your account and your system information and get everything fixed. You can find the phone number on the Nintendo website for your region under Support.